# hacer zoom a un Background-image css

Tags: javascript, html, css, style, zoom

Es un poco dificil de explicar lo que quiero hacer, asi que mejor lo explico con una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen esta como background de un Div, este es el CSS

```
.contenedor{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 25px;
}
.image1{
    background-image: url("../../../public/img/pruebas/girasoles.jpg");
}
```

Lo que quiero es que al hacer hover, la imagen haga un pequeño zoom, osea que se haga mas grande pero sin salirse del Div. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

HTML

```
<div class="contenedor image1">
    <div class="hoverBox">
        <div class="Caja">
            <div class="texto">Hola</div>
            <div class="textoOculto">Necesito aparecer</div>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Ignoren el resto de los div internos, son para el texto, el marco, etc.
Si debo poner JS no hay problema solo necesito ideas...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(mountain.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}

#example2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(mountain.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>background-size: auto (default):</h2>
<div id="example1">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>The background image is displayed in its original size.</p>
</div>

<h2>background-size: 300px 100px:</h2>
<div id="example2">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>Here, the background image is set to 300px wide and 100px high.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

La Propiedad que buscas es background-size y la modificas en un hover. Background-position puede ayudarte a mover el punto de enfoque y con un transition quizás salga un efecto genial. Juega con esos atributos y lamento no darte el código hecho

Comment: No te preocupes, con esto ya tengo donde buscar, cuando encuentre la solucion les publico el codigo.